# Menu Items Not Closing?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

I'm coding a staff panel but I'm stuck I've added a menu (navigation) but I'm stuck on how to go about opening it when clicked and closing it when clicked if open.

Here is the code i have so far;

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav">
    <?php
    $url = $_GET['url'] ? $core->clean($_GET['url']) : 'core.home';

    $query3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE url = '{$url}'");
    $array3 = $db->assoc($query3);

    if (!$array3['usergroup']) {

        $array3['usergroup'] = "invalid";
    }

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usergroups ORDER BY weight ASC");

    while ($array = $db->assoc($query)) {

        if (in_array($array['id'], $user->data['uGroupArray'])) {
            ?>



            <div class="menustyle" onclick="Radi.menuToggle('<?php echo $array['id']; ?>');">



                <div class="menutext"><?php echo $array['name']; ?></div>

            </div>

            <ul>
                <li class="menuitems"<?php if ($array['id'] != $array3['usergroup']) { ?> onclick="Radi.menuToggle('<?php echo $array['id']; ?>');" style="display: none;"<?php } ?> id="mitems_<?php echo $array['id']; ?>">

        <?php
        $query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE usergroup = '{$array['id']}' AND visible = '1' ORDER BY weight ASC");
        $i = "a";
        while ($array2 = $db->assoc($query2)) {
            ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $array2['url']; ?>" class="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $array2['text']; ?></a>
                    </li>

            <?php
            $i++;

            if ($i == "c") {

                $i = "a";
            }
        }
        ?>
            </ul>
        </li>      
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>




</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And this is the defualt code when you download radipanel;

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">

    <?php
    $url = $_GET['url'] ? $core->clean($_GET['url']) : 'core.home';

    $query3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE url = '{$url}'");
    $array3 = $db->assoc($query3);

    if (!$array3['usergroup']) {

        $array3['usergroup'] = "invalid";
    }

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM usergroups ORDER BY weight ASC");

    while ($array = $db->assoc($query)) {

        if (in_array($array['id'], $user->data['uGroupArray'])) {
            ?>

            <div class="box">

                <div class="square menu" style="background: #<?php echo $array['colour']; ?>;" onclick="Radi.menuToggle('<?php echo $array['id']; ?>');">

                    <img id="menutoggle_<?php echo $array['id']; ?>" class="menutoggle" src="_img/<?php echo ( $array['id'] != $array3['usergroup'] ) ? 'plus' : 'minus'; ?>_white.png" alt="Toggle" align="right" />

                    <strong><?php echo $array['name']; ?></strong>

                </div>

                <div class="menuitems"<?php if ($array['id'] != $array3['usergroup']) { ?> style="display: none;"<?php } ?> id="mitems_<?php echo $array['id']; ?>">

        <?php
        $query2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE usergroup = '{$array['id']}' ORDER BY weight ASC");

        $i = "a";

        while ($array2 = $db->assoc($query2)) {
            ?>

                        <a href="<?php echo $array2['url']; ?>" class="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <?php echo $array2['text']; ?>
                        </a>

            <?php
            $i++;

            if ($i == "c") {

                $i = "a";
            }
        }
        ?>

                </div>

            </div>

                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>

</div>
```

So any ideas on why my code is not doing it?

Comment: Can you please post the rendered HTML?

Comment: can you show what code is fetched on the browser in `source code`??

Comment: @all But why guys? can't you guess what's rendered? `;)`

Comment: Josh, it would be nice to see any JS you have so far. That way not only can we guide you to correct your issues, but also to eventually teach you what to take care in the future.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan This is the menu js so far http://pastebin.com/KJPa4YvT

Comment: @NoobEditor http://pastebin.com/f1hm5rmZ Source Code

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : yeah...but thinking that way, OP will find out whats the bug too!! :p :)